# LINQ query with GROUP JOIN - require additional data in the group

Tags: .net, linq

I'm just getting to grips with LINQ and I have the following scenario:

I have a database which represents sports matches between teams on various dates, organised as follows:

```
Table MATCH
___________
MatchID
MatchLocation
MatchDate


Table MATCHTEAM
________________
MatchID
TeamID
HomeOrAway
Points

Table TEAM
__________
TeamId
TeamName
```

Now I want to be able to query the database to look at all matches a particular team played in, and the associated team data for each match. So far I've been able to perform a query that does a GROUP JOIN as follows:

```
    Using MyMatchEntites As New MatchEntities
        Return (From M In MyMatchEntites.Match, _
                MT In MyMatchEntites.MatchTeam _
                Where M.MatchId = MT.Match.MatchId And _
                MT.Team.TeamId = inputTeamId _
                Select M _
                Group Join MT2 In MyMatchEntites.MatchTeam _
                On MT2.Match.MatchId Equals M.MatchId _
                Into _
                MatchTeams = Group).ToList
    End Using
```

This gives me a list of matches played in by the input team and each record has an associated list of the teams that played in the match. However, I also want to include the team name in this sublist for display purposes. How would I include the TeamName field in the MatchTeams group created in the query?

Comment: You want to retrieve all matches a team has played, that's OK, but I don't understand what you want more. Is it the data from the input team or the data from the opponent team ? If so, you said that each record you get has a list containing the teams that played in the match, so you should be able to get the team names from that list.

Comment: Both. Basically I select a team from a combobox and then I want to bring back every match in which that team played a part (either home or away), PLUS the details from MatchTeam for both teams in each match I retrieve. I want to include TeamName in this but it comes from a third table and I don't know how to include that in the Group Join clause.

Answer (score 0):

Just a guess...

Is it possible to do something like that:

```
Select M, T _
Group Join MT2 In MyMatchEntites.MatchTeam _
On MT2.Match.MatchId Equals M.MatchId _
Group Join T In MyMatchEntites.Team
On T.TeamId = MT2.TeamId
```

I'm pretty sure that you can do multiple GroupJoins with LINQ, but I don't know about retrieving multiple entities in the select clause. By the way, this would return the whole Team entity, not only the field TeamName.

Hope this helps.

Comment: Unfortunately it doesn't like that because it's expecting an INTO after the first Group Join clause.

Comment: Well, maybe you can place the second GroupJoin statement after the Into statement.

Comment: I tried that, but it then doesn't allow you to reference back to MT2.TeamId. I think I'll have to find another way of doing this. Thanks for your efforts, anyway.